# Baking multiple normal Maps form multiple materials

Tags: texture-baking, baking, normal-map

Hi I have googled and look at so many post trying to find my problem. I did not find anywhere someone with the same problem while looking.

I am trying to bake multiple normal maps from multiple matirals into one. It does now work. I tryed a lot of stuff. The video I orinally tryed to follow way this [Tips for Optimizing Game Assets in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFE6KhNKg8A). But all I got was a map with just one color. I do not know what I did wrong. There are not many stepps to follow and I tried looking up the problem but my search kept redirecting me to baking a high poly mash onto a low one. Which this is not.

Pleas help me. I probalby have an obvious mistake that I do not see.

Blender version is 3.6.4.

This is the image I **get**:

[image]

This is my **model** with only the normalmaps enabled:

[image]

These are the **baking settings**:

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file?